# Speed of Algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Suppose that an algorithm uses $5n^2 + 3^n$ bit operations to solve a problem of size $n$. Suppose that your machine can perform one bit operation in $10^{-9}$ seconds. How long does it take your algorithm to solve a problem of the sizes given below.

Note, if your algorithm takes more than $60$ seconds, answer in minutes. For more than $60$ minutes, answer in hours. For more than $24$ hours, answer in days. For more than $365$ days, answer in years. For more than $100$ years, answer in centuries.

How would one go about solving this if $n$ is equal to $20$?

Comment: Substitute $n=20$ into $(5n^2 + 3^n)\cdot 10^{-9}$, this gives the running time in seconds.

Comment: That I know, but how can i represent the answer in hours, days years or centuries as needed? @peterwhy

Comment: @choloboy If the number $t_s=(5\cdot20^2+3^{20})10^{-9}$ in seconds is greater than 60, then the number of minutes is $t_m=t_s/60$, then $t_h=t_m/60,t_d=t_h/24,t_a=t_d/365,t_c=t_a/100$ for the time in hours, days, years and centuries.

Comment: @choloboy: If you actually do the calculations, you’ll find that you don’t need to do any unit conversions anyway.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott How? I dont quite understand, im getting a pretty large decimal number as my result

Comment: @choloboy: You shouldn’t be: $(5\cdot20^2+3^{20})\cdot10^{-9}$ is a little less than $3.5$.